# Snake Pass: Are there any rewards for 100% completion?

Tags: snake-pass

Are there any rewards for achieving 100% completion in Snake Pass?

While each per-level collectible, (orbs, medals, time trials), contributes to overall completion, they don't seem to unlock any tangible in-game rewards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, achieving 100% completion appears to award you with alternate costumes for Noodle and Doodle. From [this post on GameFaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/205077-snake-pass/75182317):

> I just completed Snake Pass with all collectibles.
>
> In case anyone was wondering what the 100% completion reward was...
> It's new skins for Noodle and Doodle!
>
> Here's a picture I took too!
>
> [image: image linked in post]